# I am brand new to Firebase, and am so confused with whats going on right now. For reference, I am using Firebase with flutter. Keep getting error

Tags: firebase, flutter

```
Preparing
Analyzing dependencies
Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)
Fetching external sources
-> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_core` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '7.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_database` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_database/ios`
firebase_database: Using Firebase SDK version '7.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
  CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "firebase_core":
  In Podfile:
    firebase_core (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`)
Specs satisfying the `firebase_core (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:328:in `raise_error_unless_state'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:310:in `block in unwind_for_conflict'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:308:in `tap'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:308:in `unwind_for_conflict'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:684:in `attempt_to_activate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:254:in `process_topmost_state'
```

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in` resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in `resolve' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1074:in` block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1072:in` resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:414:in` analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:239:in `block in resolve_dependencies' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in` section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:238:in `resolve_dependencies' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:160:in` install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in` run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/bin/pod:55:in` <top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load' /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in` '
Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.